# use arrays to post to cURL with same input name

Tags: php, html, arrays, curl, input

I want to submit arrays to cURL

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <input name="comment[]" value="oh"/><br>
    <input name="comment[]" value="wow"/><br>
    <input name="comment[]" value="like"/><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and I want the result send to curl like this:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "0=oh&1=wow&2=like");
    $hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

post.php file:

```
$inputs = $_POST['comment']; print_r($inputs);
```

and result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => oh
    [1] => wow
    [2] => like
)
```

How can I send the result to cURL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post multidimensional array using CURL and get the result on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625101/post-multidimensional-array-using-curl-and-get-the-result-on-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the query string from the posted values:

```
$query_string = http_build_query($_POST['comment']);
```

And submit it via curl:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
$hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) which will do this job for you.

e.g:

```
$querystring = http_build_query($inputs);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $querystring);
$hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question is

> How do I POST an array of data using cURL?

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104607/how-to-include-array-data-in-curlopt-postfields).

You would use the function [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build a URL encoded string from your indexed `comment` array.

This code should do the trick.

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($inputs))`

You may need to set the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data, as described in the [curl_setopt documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).